# After adding a navigation bar the close button on my modal is hidden when scrolling

Tags: html, css, button, modal-dialog

I've created a JSfidle to demonstrate this issue. Basically the close button should be on the outside of the top right corner of the modal window, however since resizing and adding a verticle scrollbar to the modal the close button is now on the inside and moves when scrolling. Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g3gLvwsn/)

```
/* custom modal */

.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 750px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #f3eedd;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }

  hm1 {
    font-family: 'Londrina Sketch', cursive;
    color: #c13e18;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}

hm2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #c13e18;
    margin: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}
 hm3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
}


    pm {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 30px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your text content to its own div (eg class="content"), and apply the scroll to this one:

```
    .modalDialog > div {
  width: 750px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 0px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #f3eedd;

  overflow: visible;
}

.content{
  max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Working example here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpjQMj?editors=110

Comment: Thanks for that! I've added this and removed overflow-y: auto; from the modalDialog. This has fixed the close button, however there is now no verticle nav on the modal window...

Comment: Sorry can you explain? The 2 fiddles look the same to me except the second shows the close button at all times. The scroll bar is present in my example like it is in the original, it's just on another element. Does my fiddle work for you? If you use exactly that it will work.

Comment: Cool! I added all the changed code to my answer now. (including overflow:visible on modalDialog > div). If you're happy with my answer don't forget to click the green check (mark as best answer)!